# Where can I read the official response of UA.SE Moderators team about the weak SE policy in response to the war in Ukraine?

Tags: discussion

The SE staff has released a [rather weak and miserable statement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376743/187133) saying it refuses to impose any sanctions against the Muscovian terrorist state of "Russian" "Federation".

The statement could be different if the UA.SE Moderators and prominent users spoke out, but I failed to see any response from they who could impact the situation.

So my questions are:

- Has there been any response from UA.SE Modeartors team?
- Have any individual UA.SE users responded in any way?
- If so, where can I read it?

I carefully read the entire post, its answers and comments. There are posts from RU.SE moderators and prominent 10k+ RU.SE users. There are posts by well-known russian trolls who I fought at Politics.SE (and decided not to continue last year). The only category of people whose posts I failed to find if the prominent Ukrainian users. I think this is not acceptable.

---

Subjective part.

It's not a secret that I'm not of any high hopes about the current Mod team here. Nevertheless, **you Diamond Moderators are the only (semi-)official people out here**. There are still people who you can lead by your example. The entire UA.SE community is watching at you and… sees nothing. This has to be changed.

Comment: I trust you and would for you to become a moderator too.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for all of the UkrSE community, I can express only my own opinion. And that may be not the opinion most of UkrSE contributors will agree and/or not the opinion you personally would like to hear. Nevertheless, I'm open to any other opinion — **if a collective answer gets composed in this thread in any way and get some upvotes (so I can be sure it represents the opinion of community), I would be happy to represent it on global Meta**.

---

My personal opinion is (in short):

- Whether any boycott should be applied to Russian visitors or Russian-related subsites — I don't know.
- Whether Stack Exchange should more explicitly express support to Ukrainians — I would appreciate.

In details:

1. I am very thankful for military (i.e. volunteers, weapons, etc), refugee-assistance-related and financial support from other countries. Of course, I would be even more thankful if the other countries take even more measures (e.g. their official armies enter the battle and/or NATO closes the sky over Ukraine).
2. Also I am very thankful for various *well-aimed* forms of sanctions and boycott against Russia.
3. However for *some* of proposed or actual forms of boycott against Russia I have a mixed feeling. Like when one that is unable to bring Hitler to trial starts to torture a Hitler-faced cat instead. One part of me is pleased to observe even such kinds of support. But another part of me thinks that it's not the way a civilized person should act (IMHO, a civilized and brave person should directly enter the battle; but if they for some reason choose to stay away, they still shouldn't do anything that could harm a one having no guilt).

   But I can't say I am against such forms of boycott either. First, I'm not a specialist in this area (I know too little about social psychology or historical precedents; my purely-intuitive feeling “a civilized person shouldn't do that” may be pretty wrong). Second, I don't even imagine how harsh times are waiting for all of us; maybe even non-fully-civilized responses are “a must” in order to defeat absolutely-non-civilized offenses.

   So, for some forms of boycott I prefer to stay neutral. Coursera suspends all content from Russian universities — I honor that. ICANN decides *not* to revoke `.ru`, `.рф` and `.su` TLDs — I honor that *too*. Whether Stack Exchange decides to apply or not to apply any boycott to visitors with Russian IPs and/or to Russia-or-Russian-language-related subsites — I think I will respect both decisions. (Sorry if that not the thing you wanted to hear.)
4. I would greatly appreciate if Stack Exchange changes the look of its subsites to explicitly express its support for Ukrainians. There are multiple proposals for that (e.g. [rjmunro's](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/376770), [Sklivvz's](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/376771), [Adám's](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/376775)) with varying implementation details, e.g.: adding text, adding banner, coloring logos into blue-and-yellow; doing that only on Russia-or-Russian-language-related subsites or on all subsites; showing that for all visitors or only to visitors with Russian IPs.

<sub>P.S.: Sorry for late response.</sub>